Find a word based on "higher/lower" in alphabet
I'm currently tasked with determining a secret word provided by a server, for which I need to develop a Python script. However, I find myself struggling to get the hang of the implementation. Despite having a rough idea of the necessary steps, I'm uncertain about the specifics.
To clarify, the objective is to guess a secret word within five attempts. After each guess, the server provides feedback indicating whether the characters at specific indices in the guessed word are greater, lesser, matching, or non-existent compared to the secret word. It's essential to note that the secret word is always in lowercase.
My approach involves initially sending a string of 16 "m" characters and then analyzing the feedback from the server, which follows a consistent format but with randomized index orders.
I know my code is shitty, it just needs to work once
Feedback from server:

The character 'm' from your guess at index 0 is less than the
character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 14 does not have a
corresponding character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess    at index 6 is less than the
character at that same index in the    password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 3 is less than    the
character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm'    from your guess at index 2 is greater than the
character at that same    index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 13    does not have a
corresponding character at that same index in the    password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 7 is greater    than the
character at that same index in the password

The character    'm' from your guess at index 5 is greater than the
character at that    same index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at    index 12 does not have a
corresponding character at that same index    in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 11 does    not have a
corresponding character at that same index in the    password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 1 is less than    the
character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm'    from your guess at index 9 is greater than the
character at that same    index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 8    is greater than the
character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm' from your guess at index 10 is less than the
character at that same index in the password.

The character 'm' from    your guess at index 4 is greater than the
character at that same    index in the password.


Here's the evaluation code I'm using:
def analyze_feedback(feedback):
    greater_than = []
    less_than = []
    match = []
    no_match = []
    comparison = []
    feedback = feedback.split("\n", 1)[1]
    for line in feedback.splitlines():
        list_things = line.split()
        
        letter = list_things[2]
        index = list_things[8]
        comparison = list_things[10]
        matches = list_things[9]

        index.replace("'","")
        index = int(index)
        letter = letter.replace("'","")

        
        # print(letter, index, comparison, matches)
        if matches == "matches":
            match.append(index)
        elif comparison == "less":
            less_than.append(index)
        elif comparison == "greater":
            greater_than.append(index)
        else:
            no_match.append(index)
    return no_match, greater_than, less_than

This function parses each line of the feedback received from the server, extracting the necessary data for further processing. It returns three lists containing the indexes of unmatched, greater than, and lesser than characters.
Now, onto the function that generates the next guess:
def generate_next_guess(current_guess, comparison, previous_guess):
    guess = ""
    if comparison == "greater":
        middle_index = (ord(current_guess) + ord('a')) // 2
        guess = chr(middle_index)
    elif comparison == "less":
        middle_index = (ord(current_guess) + ord('z')) // 2
        guess = chr(middle_index)
    else:
        return current_guess

    return guess

This function calculates the character for the next guess, ensuring it's positioned between the current guess and the other end.
after that, I update the password by removing unnecessary characters:
password = ["m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m",]
length_no_match = len(no_match)
password = password[:-length_no_match]

Afterwards, I generate characters for indexes in the lesser than and greater than lists and update the password accordingly. Finally, I send the modified data back to the server for further evaluation.
for i in greater_than:
    guess = generate_next_guess(password[i], "greater")
    password[i] = guess

for i in less_than:
    guess = generate_next_guess(password[i], "less")
    password[i] = guess
result = "".join(password)

send_data_to_server(client_socket, result)

This doesn't work as it will always send the character in between the other end based on "greater/less" and I can't really figure out what should be done. In the first run it works as intended, but on the second,  third, fourth and fith try it just breaks.
Can someone help me, figuring out what needs to be done? Or link to the question that has already solved the problem :)

Are you writing a code to solve Wordle?

Store for each character the possible range in alphabet that the character can have. Initially it is from 'a' to 'z' (including). If the server e. g. says it is before 'm', new range is 'a' to 'l'. For next try use the middle of the range.

@MichaelButscher this is a really good hint, thank you
